# How can I avoid repeating my code when creating reply callbacks in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way that I could avoid repeating the function callback below in all the methods of my controllers.

```
exports.findAll = function(request, reply) {
  function callback (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      return reply(error);
    }

    return reply(data);
  }
  users.findAll(callback);
};
```

I'would like to create a method that would still have access to the reply object so I could call it in all my controller methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```js
var callback = function(reply) {
    return function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            return reply(error);
        }

        return reply(data);
    }
};
```

You can put it out of your controller methods, maybe even into separate module and use like:

```js
exports.findAll = function(request, reply) {
    users.findAll(callback(reply));
};
```